# Como llenar un select con la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema logre llenar mi lista desplegable SELECT , la conexión a base de datos funciona y me cargan los datos en mi lista todo muy bien a la hora de guardar los datos en la base de datos los guarda muy bien también, el detalle es que guarda el id y no el campo con el nombre que seleccione. El detalle es que necesito el id y el nombre para auto completar mi select como puedo hacer que guarde el nombre del vehículo y no su id.

Por ejemplo si elijo caribe su id es 1 y eso es lo que guarda yo quiero que almacene el nombre de caribe

este es mi código para llenar mi select:

```
<select  name="vehiculo" id="vehiculo" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <?php
            $query="SELECT  * FROM vehiculo";
            $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['no_unidad'].'">'.$row['vehiculo'].'</option>';
          }
        ?>
      </select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia esta línea

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['no_unidad'].'">'.$row['vehiculo'].'</option>';
```

Por

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['vehiculo'].'">'.$row['vehiculo'].'</option>';
```

Así el valor que se enviará será el nombre del vehículo por ejemplo caribe, y no su id 1 por ejemplo.

Comment: era algo tan sencillo no se a que le moví que al cambiarlo ya no me mandaba los campos en mi select por eso ya no supe que hacer pero mucha gracias funciono así como me indicas cambiando esa linea de código

Answer (score 0):

En casos de pequeños `select`, podrías usar `enum` como tipo de datos.
En caso de requerir el id y el texto del option, lo podes completar antes de insertarlo en la base con una consulta previa 
(`"SELECT vehiculo FROM vehiculos WHERE id_vehiculo=x"`) y con el resultado populas el insert/update.

Saludos!